# PrimeFaces datatable pagination shows ' no records found '

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an application using JSF2.0, Spring3 and Hibernate4.

I am displaying values in Primefaces 3.4.2 datatable pagination http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatablePagination.jsf. the problem is that the datatable shows me " no records found

"[image: displaying values from database]

and when i use a JSF2.0 dataTable without pagination, i retreive my records !

[image: displaying values from database]

this is my Xhtml file :

```
<h:form prependId="false">

    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{candidatBean.candidats}" var="c"
                 paginator="true" rows="10"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Ajax Pagination
        </f:facet>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Nom" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{c.nom}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Prenom" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{c.prenom}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Ecole" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{c.ecole}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Mail" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{c.email}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll find the cause by enabling SQL logging through `hibernate.show_sql=true` (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html).

Comment: i've enabled SQL logging to true, but i have the same problem , " no recors found " !!

Comment: Of course enabling SQL logging doesn't *solve* your problem but analyzing the SQL logs will *help you solve* the problem because it might give you hints why the query yields no results.